# What sort of handle would fit this main valve?

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture

Does anyone know what sort of handle would fit this main valve?  Prefer to avoid using the tongue and groove pliers again!

[image]

Comment: Can you get us some measurements, or something in the picture for scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a replacement handle for this situation which bites into the stem. This type of replacement handle is fine if the valve is not regularly operated and if it is not excessively hard to turn.

Comment: Interesting idea, would this universal plumbing repair handle work? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00M16DANU/

Comment: How often do you use this valve? What does this valve control? How is the condition of the rest of the valve? Sometimes it is better to replace the stem, if you can get it. Do you have a small pipe wrench or locking pliers (Vise-Grips)?

Comment: I saw that Mandle valve too and it looks good to me, but there might be cheaper ones at HD or Lowes. The type I have seen has a blade or wedge which bites into the stem.

Comment: I don't want to go back and forth on a recommendation. If the valve works acceptably with a pipe wrench or locking pliers, then just use it with that or get a universal repair handle. It can be a chore to source a new stem and things can go wrong in something as simple as replacing a stem.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you want but the only way a handle will fit on that chewed up stem is if the stem is replaced.

Anything that the handle used to engage with the stem is gone, whether it was square shoulders, knurled, fluted or flat spot. I do not see anything for the handle to engage to turn the shaft.